# JQuery animation performance in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, animation

I have a simple animation which moves some vertical bars a certain distance and then back.  I am using the animate JQuery function and with it modifying the left property of the divs.  All is well in Safari and Opera (Mac), but in Firefox (Mac) the vertical bars get distorted -- as if the rendering of the top of the bar is not in sync with the bottom.

The example is online at: http://whiskeyspider.com/.  Click any of the lighter colored bars to see the animation.  Any idea how I can make it animate more smoothly?  Thanks.

Comment: The animation works fine on Firefox (Windows)

Comment: Hey cool! I don't see any glitch but nice!

Comment: Worked fine on my Mac running FF 3.5.3 - nice work btw.

Answer (score 0):

I see this on my work Windows PC. I believe it's a display problem - lack of vsync (vertical synchronization), as they call it in PC games.

This particular PC has hardware acceleration in the graphics adapter settings set to something lower than "Full", which I guess can be causing it. Didn't try changing it to make sure, though.

[edit] oops, didn't read the question :) anyways, I didn't find many reports of this issue in Firefox, so I believe it to be system-specific. Strange that other browsers work better...